# cannot import module when npm start while uploading to server(cpanel) where as it works fine when doing in localhost

Tags: node.js, npm, cpanel, web-deployment

While i am working on the localhost everything works fine, nodejs and everything. but when i try to deploy it to the server (cpanel) after making a nodejs application. And when I do  npm start (node server.js) it does not work and i get this error.

```
stdout:
> thewebapp@1.0.0 start /home/proudpos/backend
> node server
stderr:
/home/proudpos/backend/server.js:1
import express from "express";
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! thewebapp@1.0.0 start: `node server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the thewebapp@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/proudpos/.npm/_logs/2021-08-30T02_57_23_668Z-debug.log
```

here is my package.json file,

```
{
  "name": "thewebapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cloudinary": "^1.26.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

here is my node app in cpanel,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
const express = require('express');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.